# removing item from ListView.builder Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, listview, bloc

hi may i ask how to remove an item from the ListViewBuilder,
normally it must be enough if i have an array let's call it x;
then i can remove any item that i want by using remoteAt

```
 x.removeAt(index);
```

but in this case i couldn't know exactly how can i do that.
so i don't have an x array or list in this case , see please the code below.
i just declared how can i do that if i have a list and including it inside a list builder , then i can remove any widget on the screen by calling removeAt property
thanks in advance

```
child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[BlocBuilder(
                cubit: BlocProvider.of<AppBloc>(context),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AppState state) {
                  if (state is AppUpdated && state.services.count > 0) {
                    return Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: state.services.count,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                            Dismissible(
                              key: Key(state.service.toString()),
```

Comment: calling set state after `x.removeAt(index);` would do the trick

Comment: thanks for your help, but the array that called x , is not really exist in the project. i just declared that if i have normally a list let's call it x and i want to fill this list in a listbuilder then if i want to remove any item of the widgets on the screen then it will be enought to call removeAt property. but in my case here there is just state.services.count istead of an array or list like x for example, so how can i remove any item from state.services . this is my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: state.services.count,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
    Dismissible(
      key: Key(state.service.toString()),
      onDismissed: (direction) {
         // Remove the item from the data source.
         setState(() {
             x.removeAt(index);
         });
        },
        child: //your child here (maybe listivew)
     ),
   ),
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but the array that called x , is not really exist in the project.
i just declared that if i have normally a list let's call it x and i want to fill this list in a listbuilder then if i want to remove any item of the widgets on the screen then it will be enought to call removeAt property. 
but in my case here there is just state.services.count istead of an array or list like x for example, so how can i remove any item from state.services . this is my question .

Comment: add an event to the bloc if use dismiss the particular list which does the deletion operation and there should have listed and yield the new state which gives the new list. You can not use `setState` inside `BlocBuilder` so you have to add an event.